# How to handle an unexpected json response in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm building a python script that gathers data from Instagram, based on a user list provided in my database. However, I'm running into some issues trying to handle unexpected JSON response.

To give some context, the program is fetching a username from my database table (24/7, looping over hundreds of accounts - hence the `while True:` loop), requesting a URL with that username, and expecting a certain JSON response (specifically, it's looking for `['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]` in the response). 
However when usernames aren't found on Instagram, the JSON is different, and the expected part (`['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]`) is not in there. So my script crashes.

With the current code:

```
def get_username_from_db():
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ig_users_raw WHERE `username` IS NOT NULL ORDER BY `ig_users_raw`.`last_checked` ASC LIMIT 1")
            row = cursor.fetchall()
            username = row[0]['username']
    except pymysql.IntegrityError:
        print('ERROR: ID already exists in PRIMARY KEY column')
    return username

def request_url(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
    except requests.HTTPError:
        raise requests.HTTPError(f'Received non 200 status code from {url}')
    except requests.RequestException:
        raise requests.RequestException
    else:
        return response.text

def extract_json_data(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    except requests.HTTPError:
        raise requests.HTTPError('Received non-200 status code.')
    except requests.RequestException:
        raise requests.RequestException
    else:
        print(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
        scripts = soup.find_all('script', type="text/javascript", text=re.compile('window._sharedData'))
        stringified_json = scripts[0].get_text().replace('window._sharedData = ', '')[:-1]
        j = json.loads(stringified_json)['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]
        return j

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        sleep(randint(5,15))
        username = get_username_from_db()
        url = f'https://www.instagram.com/{username}/'
        j = extract_json_data(url)
        json_string = json.dumps(j)
        user_id = j['graphql']['user']['id']
        username = j['graphql']['user']['username']
        #print(user_id)
        try:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                db_data = (json_string, datetime.datetime.now(),user_id)
                sql = "UPDATE `ig_users_raw` SET json=%s, last_checked=%s WHERE `user_id`= %s "
                cursor.execute(sql, db_data)
                connection.commit()
                print(f'{datetime.datetime.now()} - data inserted for user: {user_id} - {username}')
        except pymysql.Error:
            print('ERROR: ', pymysql.Error)
```

I'm getting the following error/traceback:

```
https://www.instagram.com/geloria.itunes/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Ministry\ig_raw.py", line 63, in <module>
    j = extract_json_data(url)
  File "D:\Python\Ministry\ig_raw.py", line 55, in extract_json_data
    j = json.loads(stringified_json)['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

Ideally, I want this to just skip past the account (in this case `geloria.itunes`), and move to the next one in the database. I might want to remove the account, or at least remove the username from the row.

In an effort to solve this myself, I experimented with `if / else` loops, but in the case where it would continue, I'd just be looping over the same account.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can tackle this specific issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to figure out why exception occurred.

The reason why you're getting this error is because you're telling `json` to parse invalid (non-JSON) string.

Just run this example with URL you've provided in traceback:

```py
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/geloria.itunes/")
print(r.status_code)  # outputs 404(!)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
scripts = soup.find_all('script', type="text/javascript", text=re.compile('window._sharedData'))
stringified_json = scripts[0].get_text().replace('window._sharedData = ', '')[:-1]

print(stringified_json)
# j = json.loads(stringified_json)  # will raise an exception
```

Output:

> `\n(function(){\n  function normalizeError(err) {\n...
>   ...
>   stringify(normalizedError));\n      })\n    }\n  })\n}());`

As you can see `stringified_json` is not a valid JSON string.

---

As you mentioned it is invalid because this instagram page is hidden or does not exist (HTTP status code is `404 Not Found`). And you're passing the wrong response to `json.loads()` because **you have no checks for response status code** in your script.

The following `except` clauses did not catch "404 case" because you've received a valid HTTP response therefore there is no exception to raise:

```py
except requests.HTTPError:
    raise requests.HTTPError('Received non-200 status code.')
except requests.RequestException:
    raise requests.RequestException
```

So basically you have 2 ways to deal with this issue:

- check for response HTTP status code manually like `if r.status_code != 200 ...`
- or use `raise_for_status()` [method](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes) to throw an exception if `400 <= r.status_code < 600`

---

> I might want to remove the account, or at least remove the username from the row.

Well, your question here sounds a bit vague. I can just give an idea.

For example - if 404 page encountered, you can `raise` your custom exception when dealing with response, catch it later in `__main__`, delete record from database and continue with other pages:

```py
class NotFoundError(Exception):
    """ my custom exception for not found pages """
    pass

...  # other functions

def extract_json_data(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if r.status_code == 404:
        raise NotFoundError()  # page not found

    # if any other error occurs (network unavailable for example) - an exception will be raised

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    scripts = soup.find_all('script', type="text/javascript", text=re.compile('window._sharedData'))
    stringified_json = scripts[0].get_text().replace('window._sharedData = ', '')[:-1]
    return json.loads(stringified_json)['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        sleep(randint(5, 15))
        username = get_username_from_db()
        url = f'https://www.instagram.com/{username}/'
        try:
            j = extract_json_data(url)
        except NotFoundError:
            delete_user_from_db(username)  # implement: DELETE FROM t WHERE username = ...
            continue  # proceed for next user page

        # rest of your code:
        # json_string = json.dumps(j)
        # user_id = j['graphql']['user']['id']
        # ...
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan! Your suggestions helped to overcome this 'issue' .